# select a row in a second level a childtable in jtable jquery

Tags: jquery, jtable, rows, selected

I need your help, how do I select a row in a child table with two levels?
This works well:

```
var $FilasHijas = $('.jtable-child-table-container > .jtable-child-table-container').jtable('getRowByKey', $DetalleDeudaID);
$('.jtable-child-table-container > .jtable-child-table-container').jtable('selectRows', $FilasHijas);
```

but to do this:

```
$selectedDetalleRows = $('.jtable-child-table-container > .jtable-child-table-container').jtable('selectedRows');
```

the variable $selectedDetalleRows is empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was able to solve it with:

```
var $selectedRows = $('#TableContainer>.jtable-main-container>.jtable>tbody>.jtable-child-row .jtable-row-selected');
```

Where of corse `#TableContainer` is the Main-Tablecontainer, which is not named in your example, so you will have to change this.

Find a more complete answer with working example here:
[jQuery JTable Problems to find selected rows in ChildTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913194/jquery-jtable-problems-to-find-selected-rows-in-childtable/40922910#40922910)